# How to correctly use a forloop with a pandas dataframe so that output is printed correct number of times

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, for-loop

So I have some sample code here that goes as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = range(1, 12)
arr1 = np.random.randint(x)
arr2 = np.array(x)
arr3 = np.random.randint(x)
arr4 = np.random.randint(x)
arr5 = np.random.randint(0, 2, 11)



dict_df = {
    'arr1' : arr1,
    'arr2' : arr2,
    'arr3' : arr3,
    'arr4' : arr4,
    'arr5' : arr5
}
d = pd.DataFrame(dict_df)
for i in d.index:
    number = d['arr1'][i]
    for num in d['arr5']:
        if num == 1:
            print('Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is {}'.format(number))
```

What I have done is create a basic dataframe with a bunch of random numbers in each column. Except the last column which has a combination of only ones and zeros. Currently the output to this code is:

```
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 0
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 0
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 0
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 0
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 0
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 0
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 0
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 0
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 2
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 2
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 2
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 2
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 1
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 1
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 1
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 1
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 3
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 3
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 3
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 3
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 2
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 2
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 2
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 2
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 3
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 3
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 3
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 3
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 5
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 5
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 5
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 5
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 4
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 4
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 4
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 4
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 8
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 8
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 8
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 8
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 8
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 8
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 8
Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is 8
​
```

So it is clear I am missusing the for loops in this situation. The output I was looking to get, was for the code to look through each individual number in column arr5, and then decipher if it was equal to 1 or 0. If it was equal to one, I wanted the code to print that it was equal one and then also print the correlating number for that same row in column arr1. How can I change the code to receive this output? Thanks!

Comment: do you want the result as the same `d[d.arr5==1]['arr1'] `?

Comment: @Bear Brown  Yes, But I would like it to print out everytime there is a 1. So say there are 65 ones in column arr5, then it should print out 65 lines of code in the way it did in my question.

Comment: Your code produces `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'range'` for `arr1 = np.random.randint(x)` - which version of Numpy? please provide [mre].

Comment: @wwii hm... the code from question is work for me.

Comment: @wwii I am not getting that error. I have copy and pasted the code directly and I am getting the output shown above.

Comment: `print('\n'.join([f'Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is {x}' for x in d[d.arr5==1]['arr1']]))` is it what you want?

Comment: Is that the full code from `for i in d.index` foward? Can you put it in as a answer?

Comment: .. version issue - my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
dict_df = {
    'arr1' : arr1,
    'arr2' : arr2,
    'arr3' : arr3,
    'arr4' : arr4,
    'arr5' : arr5
}
d = pd.DataFrame(dict_df)

print('\n'.join(
    [f'Num equals 1, and its number in arr1 is {x}' for x in d[d.arr5==1]['arr1']]
))
```